# How do I connect my domain from Domain.com to serve my website with Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: web-services, google-cloud-platform, dns, web-hosting, google-cloud-dns

[image]First of all, I'm very new at this, with barely idea of anything about serving/domain websites.
I've tried everything this weekend almost non-stop, I just want to serve my domain that I bought in Domain.com, through Google Cloud services since I have the free 300 USD trial.

What I did so far was creating an instance of VM with "Compute Engine" service, which is probably a mess since I touched the configs a lot. Then I created a bucket to store data with "Storage" service. Then again in Google Cloud Platform I created a zone in Cloud DNS using "Network Services". Again, I prolly messed a lot of the configs in there.

I will provide photos of the mess I did, don't worry (and sorry for the bad crop I had to put the photos all together somehow).

Well and then finally my domain (franfonse.com) that I bought through www.Domain.com.
Trying to configure things out I added, verified, deleted and modified things a lot in the DNS records and Servernames.

Can someone just tell me what I should do? Because as I said I'm very new in this and I don't even know what is right or wrong of the things that I did anymore, I gave up.

Please, help!

Comment: The TTL for your DNS settings (A Record) is 604800 - 7 days. That number is the number of seconds for a record to expire. When you change a DNS resource record, you typically must wait for the TTL value of the old value to expire. You have some time to wait. Edit the A and CNAME records now and change the TTL to 3600. Do not change the SOA or NS records. Then wait until the old records expire next week. Once you have everything working change the A and CNAME TTL to 86400 (one day). While waiting, study how DNS servers work.

Comment: Another item, show your network security group settings for this VM instance. Also, you show two IP addresses for the DNS A record, but you VM has on IP address (104.196.225.83). What is the 34.82.61.118 IP address for? What is the top-right screenshot for? I have a feeling you are trying to mix a VM with Cloud Storage. Did you configure an HTTP(S) Load Balancer somewhere?

Comment: Your bottom left picture shows six nameservers. This is usually not correct. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

**To connect you domain to your website on GCP** you should follow next steps:

1. [create public managed zone](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart#create_a_managed_public_zone) on Google Cloud DNS (if you want to use it, it's possible to use any DNS hosting you want)
2. replace existed NS records with obtained at Google Cloud DNS (in your case records `ns-cloud-b1-googledomains.com`, `ns-cloud-b2-googledomains.com`, `ns-cloud-b3-googledomains.com` and `ns-cloud-b4-googledomains.com`) at domain registrar side (in your case DOMAIN.COM)
3. [reserve external static IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static) for your VM
4. [create VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstarts) using reserved external static IP address and do not forget to enable HTTP/HTTPS access
5. [create A record](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart#create_a_new_record)
6. install web server and configure web site
7. check if required ports open with command `nmap -Pn EXTERNAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM` and configure firewall if necessary
8. access your web site by domain name http://franfonce.com

As it was suggested by *@John Hanley*, **it's mandatory to use only necessary NS records at domain registrar side** (in your case DOMAIN.COM). You should remove `lia.ns.cloudflare.com` and `memphis.ns.cloudflare.com` if you want to use Google Cloud DNS or remove `ns-cloud-b1-googledomains.com`, `ns-cloud-b2-googledomains.com`, `ns-cloud-b3-googledomains.com` and `ns-cloud-b4-googledomains.com` if you prefer Cloudflare DNS.

**I do not recommend to change default TTL settings** unless you do know for sure how they work, meanwhile you can set suggested by *@John Hanley* values instead of yours.

As I can see, **you configured Cloudflare as DNS for your domain**:

```
$ dig NS franfonse.com 
...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
franfonse.com.          86400   IN      NS      memphis.ns.cloudflare.com.
franfonse.com.          86400   IN      NS      lia.ns.cloudflare.com.

$ dig A franfonse.com
...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
franfonse.com.          300     IN      A       104.196.225.83

$ dig A www.franfonse.com 
...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.franfonse.com.      300     IN      A       104.196.225.83
```

and **everything looks good at DNS side**, but your site doesn't work:

```
This site can’t be reached

www.franfonse.com refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

and if we check current status of firewall:

```
$ nmap -Pn 104.196.225.83
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-03-23 10:20 CET
Nmap scan report for 83.225.196.104.bc.googleusercontent.com (104.196.225.83)
Host is up (0.13s latency).
Not shown: 996 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 11.49 seconds
```

we found that **ports 80 and 443 are closed**.

**To solve issue with firewall** you should open ports on firewall - go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM` -> click `EDIT` -> go to `Firewall` section and check `Allow HTTP traffic` and `Allow HTTP traffic` -> click `Save`. After that, check again with command `nmap -Pn 104.196.225.83` if ports 80/443 (http/https) are open.

Comment: Thank you so so much!!! Now I'm gonna try figure how to deploy my Angular app with it :)

Comment: Thank you for confirmation! Please mark my answer as accepted. You can always rely on community.